# Normalization (statics) in bigquery: How should I fix my code to get normalized numbers?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to normalize the data in bigquery 
but I got an error massage like below: 
  "SELECT list expression references column test which is neither grouped nor aggregated" 
and (test- AVG(test)) is underlined.

I know Python or other tool is easy to normalize the data 
but I have to do that in bigquery.

How should I change this code?

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN STDDEV_POP(test) IS NOT NULL AND STDDEV_POP(test) > 0
  THEN
   (test - AVG(test))/ STDDEV_POP(test)
  ELSE
   NULL
  END AS test_normalized
FROM temp
```

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I don't know BigQuery. But if it supports window functions you should be able to just add OVER() after your aggregates to avoid that syntax constraint.

Comment: Also, it's worth putting explicitly that you are talking about normalization in the statistical, rather than database theoretical sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want window functions.  I would go for:

```
SELECT ( (test - AVG(test) OVER () ) / 
         NULLIF(STDDEV_POP(test) OVER (), 0) 
       ) AS test_normalized
FROM temp;
```

This will standardize/normalize the value of `test` in each row.

Comment: I tired AVG(test) OVER() but still get the same error massage.

Comment: @p1kas0 . . . There is no aggregation in the query in this answer, so that error message is not appropriate.

Comment: There is implicit aggregation here - because of presence of aggregation function AVG()

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant . . . It is a *window* function, not an *aggregation* function in this context.  No `GROUP BY` is needed.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Was too fast in glancing the query. How about STDDEV_POP()

Comment: Oops, sorry again  - same thing. Will try by myself when get to PC :o)

Comment: you should add OVER() to all AVG(test) and STDDEV_POP(test) instances in your statement

Comment: hmmm (test - AVG(test) OVER())/ STDDEV_POP(test) OVER() is still not working, same error message

Comment: Oops, I forgot to write NULLIF() ! I tried it and the problem was solved!! THANK YOU !!